# Function just 'disappears' the program

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

```
trace('a');
mapData = t.getData(false);
trace('b');
```

I have absolutely no idea what's going on here. `t` is a `flixel.tile.FlxTilemap`, by the way.

When I run this code, my game instantly crashes. I get the `a` message but not the `b` message. Even stranger, I inserted a trace into my copy of `FlxTilemap.hx`, right at the start of the definition of `getData`, but that trace never runs either. What is going on?

Comment: What target is this? Cpp likes to crash silently, but neko usually gives you a stacktrace at least.

Comment: Is t initialized? My first guess is that it is null.

Comment: @Gama11 CPP, unfortunately. None of the app compiles on neko.

Comment: @EricBernier This is inside a game's saving routine, which means to run this code I need to start the game and thus see the tilemap. In other words, yes it's initialized. **EDIT:** Scratch that. Self-answer incoming...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of *those* questions, one of those where it's perfectly natural and you simply forget what you did someplace else.

In my case, as was pointed out, `t` wasn't actually set. This is because I reserved floor number 0 for a special area that hasn't been implemented yet... and set it to `null` in the meantime...